# Problema con matrices y estructuras en C

Tags: c, matrices, estructuras

Resulta que he estado resolviendo algunos ejercicios en una plataforma llamada "CodeSignal".

En un problema, especifico el problema 8, aparece el siguiente codigo:

```
// Arrays are already defined with this interface:
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
//
//
int matrixElementsSum(arr_arr_integer matrix) {

}
```

La funcion `matrixElementsSum` obviamente recibe una matriz que es creada a partir de las dos estructuras antes mencionadas.

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo iterar en la matriz dada en la función? Ya que para resolver el problema necesito imprimir la matriz, para lo cual necesito el una variable o un "algo" que me diga el numero de filas y el numero de columnas.

**NOTA: Solo puedo agregar código a la función, no puedo hacer más funciones ni más estructuras**

**Editado: Alguna Forma para ingresar la matriz por teclado**

Lo intente de la siguiente manera, pero no me funciona el el for anidado

```
typedef struct arr_arr_integer
{
  int size;
  struct
  {
    int size;
    int *arr;
  }*arr;
}arr_arr_integer;

arr_arr_integer alloc_arr_integer(int len)
{
  arr_arr_integer a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(int) * len) : NULL};
  return a;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

  int Filas,Columnas,len;

  printf("Ingrese el Numero de Filas [-]:");
  scanf("%d",&Filas);
  printf("Ingrese el Numero de Columnas [|]:");
  scanf("%d",&Columnas);

  len = Filas*Columnas;

  arr_arr_integer Matrix = alloc_arr_integer(len);

  for (int i = 0; i < Filas; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < Columnas; j++)
    {
      scanf("%d",&Matrix.arr[i].arr[j]);
    }
  }

 matrixElementsSum(Matrix)

}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a realizar el trabajo del preprocesador:

```
typedef struct arr_arr_integer {
  int size;
  struct {
    int size;
    int *arr;
  } *arr;
} arr_arr_integer;
```

> ¿ Cómo puedo iterar en la matriz dada en la función ?

Pues ahora que sabemos exactamente con qué estamos trabajando, es sencillo:

```
int matrixElementsSum(arr_arr_integer matrix) {
  for( unsigned row = 0; row < matrix.size; ++row ) {
    for( unsigned col = 0; col < matrix.arr->size; ++col ) {
      int value = matrix.arr[row].arr[col];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, llevaba días partiéndome la cabeza con ese problema.

Comment: ¿Sabe alguna forma de ingresar los datos a la matriz? Edite la pregunta para que me pudiera ayudar.